# Jenkins Gerrit Trigger and Periodically Build

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Currently all my builds triggered by Gerrit and I'm looking for the way to make nightly builds directly from the master (I need to run different test-set at night). Is there some build-in option to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by using option "This build is parameterized".
You need to specify the string as described here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger#GerritTrigger-Using%22BuildNow%22

> Add a String parameter called GERRIT_REFSPEC with the default value refs/heads/master